# How to generate every combination from a given amount of integers

Tags: list, prolog

I found this code which does exactly what I want: gets a list of integers, and generates every combination.

```
perm([H|T], Perm) :-
   perm(T, SP),
   insert(H, SP, Perm).
perm([], []).

insert(X, T, [X|T]).
insert(X, [H|T], [H|NT]) :-
   insert(X, T, NT).
```

Now what I want to do is, if one permutation does not meet some criteria, I want perm to return another result. So, and sorry for the lack of vocabulary, I want the same effect that would happen if I would execute that code, got a solution, and typed <kbd>;</kbd> to get more results. I believe this is a very simple idea but I can't see it right now.

So, pseudocode would be:

```
enumerate(inputList, outputNodes, OutputArcs) :-
   perm(inputList,OutputPermutation),
   getArcs(OutputPermutation,OutputArcs),%I want to build the OutputArcs, then check for every element to be unique, if it isn't, generate another list with perm, if it IS, return said list as accepted)
   areArcsNumberUniques(OutputArcs,OutputArcs),%TODO now is when I do not know how to make the call, here if it is valid, end, if it isn't, call perm again)
```

So I would need to understand how do I go about this. Also, any other ideas about the problem are welcome, since I'm brute forcing my way because I'm unable to find any type of algorithm or pattern to solve the actual problem (which I've asked about before. This is my attempted solution, just in order to give an actual answer to the exercise...)

edit: query:

```
enumerate([a-b,b-c], EnumNodos, EnumArcos).
```

expected output:

```
EnumNodos = [enum(3,a), enum(1,b), enum(2,c)],

EnumArcos = [enum(2,a‐b), enum(1,b‐c)]
```

This would be like the end game goal, where I get a list of arcs where each arc has an unique value that is equal to substracting the values of its nodes (every node also has an unique value).

And so far, since I did not find any way to do this algorithmically, I thought about trying every possibility (basically I cannot get an unique way to do this, trees with different branches seem different to me, and only restriction is that there are N nodes and N-1 arcs).

edit more examples:

```
    6a
  5    4
1b      2e
2       3
3c      5f
1
4d

 EnumNodos = [enum(6,a), enum(1,b), enum(2,e), enum(3,c), enum(5,f), enum(4,d)],

EnumArcos = [enum(5,a‐b), enum(4,a-e), enum(3,e-f), , enum(2,b-c), enum(1,c-d)]


    5a
  4   3
1b      2e
1       2
3c      4f

EnumNodos = [enum(5,a), enum(1,b), enum(2,e), enum(3,c), enum(4,f)],

EnumArcos = [enum(4,a‐b), enum(3,a-e), enum(1,b-c), , enum(2,e-f)]

    5a
  4    3
1b      2e
2
3c      
1
4d




    9a
  8    7    
1b      2e
 6      4
7c      6f
2       2
5d      4g
3       1
8h      3i
```

Comment: For a moment, make believe the code is already there... Please specify some simple (but not trivial) examples of queries you would want to use, together with the answers you expect.

Comment: The code you found already is about permutations, not combinations / variations...

Comment: @repeat I just added what I expect. About the permutation/combination thing, my bad. I never use permutation as a noun/verb/whatever to describe what I'm doing, I think of it as a type of combination. Not that is right, it's just how I think of it, so probably wrong choice of words.

Comment: I do not quite get it (yet)... So the challenge is to assign a different integer to each node such that the differences (of nodes connected by arcs) are unique? Shouldn't the arc `b-c` have an assigned value of `-1` instead of `1`? Or is this about absolute differences?

Comment: Some more concrete examples would surely help!

Comment: It would be indeed -1 but it's done in absolute values so arcs are from 1 to N-1, you are completly right. I will add more examples but this are done by me by hand (as you would solve a logic puzzle). And the challenge is as you said, yes, nodes have to be assigned a value from 1 to N where N is number of nodes and arcs are the same, unique values from 1 to N-1